# Feature to remind users to accept answers

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, accepted-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remind new users to choose some answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69775/remind-new-users-to-choose-some-answers)

It would be nice to have automated messages going to users who have asked a question but did not accept an answer after 1 week. Many questions are left unchecked with no feedback from the user who asked the question.

Comment: OK, [random](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79577/create-a-system-generated-comment-for-users-with-0-accept-rate/79583#79583). I concede. *Mea Culpa.*

Answer (score 0):

Just to let you know there is already a mesage on your user profile.

If you scroll down to that question it reminds you to start a bounty on it or accept an answer for. it.

Comment: start bounty on what??? And what is meeage. What i suggested is an automatic email be sent to users reminding them to accept an answer.

Comment: @Husseim to start a bounty on the question so that you might get the right answer and what about meeage?

Comment: i think you misunderstood the question. Bounty has nothing to do with this. Read my comment above

Comment: @Hussein ok sorry +1